Why Narada is known as someone who creates quarrels?
In Bengali culture, Narada is known as someone who instigates quarrels and disagreements. People are afraid of taking his name, and they think that if they do, a quarrel is inevitable. People also do not name their male child as "Narada".
He is a great devotee. Why his reputation is so bad? Is this local folk belief or is this based on Sastras?

Maybe due to tv shows and movies

@Vatapatrashaayi Ha Ha. Possible.

Is this local folk belief or is this based on Sastras?
This is mentioned in mahābhārata :
udyoga parva C :

See, O mātali, if any bridegroom may be had here, acceptable to thee. If no one can be found, we shalt, if thou likest, go hence to some
other part of the world.' Thus addressed, mātali answered nārada,
saying, 'O celestial Rishi, it behoveth me not to do anything that may
be disagreeable to dwellers of heaven. The gods and the dānavas,
though brothers, are ever at hostility with each other. How can I,
therefore, make an alliance with those that are our enemies? Let us
repair, therefore, to some other place. It behoveth me not to search
among the dānavas. As regards thyself, I know thy heart is ever set
on fomenting quarrels.'"

harivaṃśa viṣṇuparva chapter 1 :

sa tu kelikilo vipro bhedashIlashcha nAradaH | sushliShTAnapi loke.asminbhedaya.Nllabhate ratim ||2-1-30
This vipra, nārada always tries to create quarrels between people. He loves to create differences among people who are otherwise living in
harmony.
kaNDUyamAnaH satataM lokAnaTati cha~nchalaH | ghaTamAno narendrANAM tantrairvairANi chaiva hi ||2-1-31
He is restless and always travels around inducing quarrels. He takes pleasure in causing fights between kings by various ways and means.


According to the Harvinshapurana chapter this is a statement made by Kansa about Narada. Kansa being a khalapatra his opinion about Divine Beings must not be taken as fact.

as far as I know, there is no mīmāṃsā rule which states that weightage of a statement has to be analyzed by the background of the person. In this case if kaṃsa had made a wrong or incorrect statement then the narrator (vaiśaṃpāyana) or writer (vyāsa) would have documented it using appropriate grammar indicating that the statement made by by kaṃsa was wrong/incorrect.

@ekantika If this is correct then is this statement by Kamsa in the same chapter also correct
भवन्तो हि यथाकामं मोदन्तां विगतज्वराः ।
मां च वो नाथमाश्रित्य नास्ति देवकृतं भयम् ।। २९ ।
He says you all have nothing to fear from the Devatas if take refuge in me? So was Kamsa right about this as well? People who take refuge in Kamsa need not fear the Devatas?

@Dr.user44690 last line of same chapter answers your question - After prattling valiantly like this, kaMsa went to his home.

Doesn't mean they are wrong. Maybe he prattled correctly. And why isn't the above statement about Narada also prattle? If that is prattle so is the above.

statement about narada is not a prattle because it gets validated in the same/previous chapter which says that devas "confidential" plan to kill kamsa was leaked by narada to kamsa. Also matali validates it.

Nārada was the son of Brahmā, born from his lap, from his right thumb Dakṣa, from his mind Sanaka and others and from his left thumb a daughter called Vīraṇī.
According to Vishnu Purana [Book-1, Chapter 15, slokas: 82-102,  Page:98-99] Daksha created living creatures, as commanded by Brahmá. and espoused Asikní, the daughter of the patriarch Vírańa, begetting mighty sons, through whom he expected the world should be peopled. They were called Haryaśvas.
Finding that the Haryaśvas also were interested in the procreation of children Nārada, the Devarishi approached and told them as follows:

Oh! Haryaśvas! You who are exceptionally vital people seem to be
trying to procreate children. But, you have not enquired as to whether
there is enough space on earth for such large numbers of people. You
are just like children who know nothing about the world. How will you
procreate people? Since you could live absolutely free in the sky, why
do you not find out the limit of the earth?
-Vishnu Purana 1.15.92-94

The Haryaśvas thereupon ran away in different places to find out the limit of the earth, and they have not, like the rivers which entered the ocean, returned yet.
At the loss of the Haryaśvas in the above manner, Dakṣha created the Śabalāśvas, whom also Nārada sent away to various parts of the earth. Dakṣa again created five thousand people whom also Nārada drove away in the above manner
Daksha, on finding that all these sons had vanished, was angry and sad at this, cursed Nārada thus:

Well, Nārada! my children roam about like this because of you. 
Therefore, you too in future will be roaming about without a permanent abode. 
Moreover, you will have rebirth as my son.

- Vishnu Purana 1.15.101.


Thus, the curse of Daksha has caused Narada to roam around without staying in a place and spreading and instigating quarrels and disagreements.
Update-1: Dakṣa's curse on Nārada appears in Shiva Purana [Rudra-Samhita, Sati Khanda, Chapter-13, slokas: 1-40] too. In sloka-38, Daksha says roaming ever in the worlds your feet will never be steady anywhere.
Update-2: Incident of Dakṣa curses Nārada appears in Bhāgavata Purana[Book-6, Sixth Skandha, Chapter-5, slokas: 1-44] also. In sloka-43, Daksha says you will not get a resting place while wandering through the worlds.

I checked the Vishnu Purana and this verse 1.15.102 doesn't mention any such curse given by Daksha to Narada. It says that Daksha cursed Narada but not precisely what the curse was. https://sa.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A3%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D/%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%A5%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%83/%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%A7%E0%A5%AB

@Dr. user44690 , तां श्चापि नष्टान् विज्ञाय पुत्रान् दक्षः प्रजापतिः ।
क्रोधं चक्रे महाभागो नारदं स शशाप च ॥ १,१५.१०१ ॥
This is sloka where in Daksha curses Narada.  That was a typo. Please read as 101 Instead of 102. My apologies. I have update the post. Thanks for pointing this out. In order to find out the text of curse, you need Bhāsyam, please go for a version of Vishnu Purana with Bhāsyam. Good Luck!

I don't see how Bhashyam is supposed to tell you more than the Purana itself. Which bhashyam in particular you are referring to?

@Dr. user44690 please check the updates in the post.

Cool. Thanks for the references. I think this answer is much better now.
